# HTML5 Server Geolocation (NOT client location)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I use the HTML5 implementation of gelocation (navigator.geolocation) to show client location on a google map, using the Google maps API. This is easy.

What I would like, however, is to also put the server location on a map, i.e. 'you are here, your server is here'. I cannot see how to easily do this.

I could just scrape a page like whatsmyip for coordinates, but it seems like this should be built into the API. Am I just missing it?

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 geolocation api is implemented by the browser and uses a mix of  information potentially including WiFi signals, IP address, or a GPS module. It does not have access to that information for the sever, nor is it common to care about the sever location.

All of which is to say the HTML5 geolocation api does support locating the server and you will need to provide the coordinates by some other means (most likely some form of Geo IP database).

Answer (score 0):

I just scraped using php:

```
function ip_details($ip) {
    //$json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}

$details = ip_details("8.8.8.8");

$_SESSION['user']['serverextip'] = $details->ip;
$_SESSION['user']['serverloc'] = $details->loc;
```